# Null reference object trying to access custom setting in sandbox using APEX

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have created a Protected/List custom setting object in my org (not a managed package)

[image]

It's Custom fields are:

[image]

I created a dataset named: `test` with relevant values (I had another dataset with a ' ' space, thought this causes the problem.

[image: test is a dataset in my sandbox]

[image: Details of the test dataset]

When I try to access the dataset from APEX, I keep getting Null reference error.

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object (error in line 15)
```

Code snippet:  (code is in apex class - not @test)

```
14: Netsuite_Integration__c m_nsi  = Netsuite_Integration__c.getValues('test');
ERROR LINE: 15: system.debug('15 m_nsi.NS_Email__c:' + m_nsi.NS_Email__c);
```

Already tried:

- Already Tried getValues, getInstance
- Recreated the object again in Sandbox (known issue)
- Created several datasets with different names (removed space)

While coding, developer console does recognizes, and autocompletes

[image]

ideas?

Comment: Is this code executing within a unit test?

Comment: @MarkKeats the code is in APEX class, but it fails in every run, can't deploy, can't test, if this is what you mean

Comment: The custom setting is not in a managed package is it?

Comment: I understand the code in inside a class, but what is executing the code? The error message implies that there is no record called 'test' for that custom setting - and the most obvious cause would be that it's executing within the context of a test.

Comment: @BarCotter - not a managed package

Comment: @MarkKeats It's executed within a testclass in my sandbox. test is a valid dataset, that exist in my sandbox as well) *ignore the name: test - it was just a trial I had when original name didn't work.

Comment: Unless you specify the `seealldata=true` attribute (which I don't recommend) then the test will not be able to access this data. You would need to create the custom setting record within your test, or inside a `@testsetup` method.

Comment: @MarkKeats that's it. feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: @Saariko - Done. Glad it helped you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you specify the [seealldata=true](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm) attribute (which I don't recommend) then the test will not be able to access this data. You would need to create the custom setting record within your test, or inside a [@testsetup](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses) method.

Comment: This is allbit misleading. Even that we are referencing "variables" which one would consider that are accessible in @test methods. You still need to create the custom object in your test.

Note, that if you refer to a specific dataset in your code, you will need to keep the same name in your code (test code and production code)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to handle this within a test utility class, that creates an instance of the custom settings,.  Then your test code can call that class to setup the custom Setting.  Either that, or create it manually within each test class.